# How to use each row of file with loadtxt?

Tags: python

Ok so I have a long file with 13 columns, the ones I want to use are: particle velocity x component, vel y component, and vel z. I want to put each component of the velocity (for each row in the file, i.e. each particle) into an array then compute the modulus. However I can't get it to do that. It gives me an array of [[x1,x2,x3,....], [y1,y2,y3...], [z1,z2....]] then works the modulus of that. What I've got is

```
import numpy as np 

v_x = np.loadtxt('data.txt',usecols=(1,))
v_y = np.loadtxt('data.txt',usecols=(2,))
v_z = np.loadtxt('data.txt',usecols=(3,))

vel = np.array([v_x,v_y,v_z])
mod_vel = np.linalg.norm(vel)

print vel, mod_vel
```

I have tried doing

```
f = open('data.txt')
for line in f:
    stuff
```

but that doesn't work either. Any help please?

Comment: What's wrong with the `for line in f` bit, why doesn't that work, so long as you do `f.readlines()`, the `line` there is the full row of text

Comment: it just repeatedly print outs the same thing (the modulus of the array holding everything) for every line in the file

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your txt file is a kind of this (tab separated):

> 1    2    3
>
> 4    5    6
>
> 7    8    9

Code:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    t = f.readlines()
splitted = [l[:-1].split("\t") for l in t]
v_x = [l[0] for l in splitted]
v_y = [l[1] for l in splitted]
v_z = [l[2] for l in splitted]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your method and between the single loadtxt column reads and array concatenation, it is transposing your matrix.

The easiest thing to do is to just select the columns you need all in 1 line:

```
vel = np.loadtxt('data.txt', usecols=(1,2,3))
```

Alternatively, you could transpose your vel matrix

```
vel = np.array([v_x,v_y,v_z]).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I'd go with a recarray. I tend to try and use them when reading in data via loadtxt just for the cleanliness.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt(
        'data.txt',
        usecols=(1,2,3),
        delimiter=',',
        dtype=[
            ('vx', 'f8'),
            ('vy', 'f8'),
            ('vz', 'f8')
            ]
        )

norm = np.linalg.norm([data['vx'], data['vy'], data['vz']])
```